# ImportError: cannot import name indexes

Tags: django-haystack, uwsgi

I get this error when I run uwsgi the first time:
ImportError: cannot import name indexes

When I cancel uwsgi and run it again it works but the site slows down and 502 error appears randomly. With django dev server or with HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS = False it works fine.

Any idea whats wrong?

Full Traceback:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 36, in delayed_loader
   return getattr(trans, real_name)(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 193, in activate
   _active[currentThread()] = translation(language)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 176, in translation
   default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
   app = import_module(appname)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 43, in import_module
   __import__(name)

 File "/home/user/prject/apps/external/haystack/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
   from haystack.sites import site

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_haystack-1.1.0-py2.6.egg/haystack/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
   handle_registrations()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_haystack-1.1.0-py2.6.egg/haystack/__init__.py", line 151, in handle_registrations
   search_sites_conf = importlib.import_module(settings.HAYSTACK_SITECONF)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 43, in import_module
   __import__(name)

 File "/home/user/project/search_sites.py", line 4, in <module>
   haystack.autodiscover()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_haystack-1.1.0-py2.6.egg/haystack/__init__.py", line 121, in autodiscover
   importlib.import_module("%s.search_indexes" % app)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 43, in import_module
   __import__(name)

 File "/home/user/project/apps/activity/search_indexes.py", line 1, in <module>
   from haystack import indexes

ImportError: cannot import name indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

File "/home/user/prject/apps/external/haystack/init.py"
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_haystack-1.1.0-py2.6.egg/haystack/init.py"

the package: haystack in two place,
do you want to use installed version or copy it to your app path? 
remove one of it.